# Dynamically determine a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a data entry Userform, which asks the user to enter also the section where the data should be added. This is determined my either it is 001-2023 or 002-2023 or 003-2023 and so on as marked in the screenshot below.

[image]

How can I determine a Range using the input from user and then add row in between, for example if the user chooses 001-2023, the data should be added in a new row after E001-34 and if the user chooses 002-2023, the data should be added in the section below in 002-2023

I have tried something like in the screenshot, but I don't have the idea how to fetch the value for next limit. For example, if a user selects 001-2023, the value of x is the upper limit but the lower limit y I can't fetch and set

```
Dim x As String

Dim y As String

Dim n As Long

Dim i As Long
   
n = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 12 To n

    If Cells(i, "J").Value = part.Value Then

    x = "J" & i

    End If

   Next i

   For i = 12 To n

    If Cells(i, "J").Value = part.Value Then

    y = "J" & i

    End If

   Next i
  
   Tabelle3.Activate
     
   emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("x:y")) + 1
```

[[image]]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEvjm.png)

Comment: It's hard to tell what's in column "J" and row "12".  can you make your question in a "raw" sheet (a sheet where there is only the relevant data)?

Comment: there is nothing in J12, just using it as a starting point for looping

Comment: I have attached a complete sheet

Comment: I'm sorry I can't get the gist (essence) of this.  I'll have to bow out.  Best to you.

Comment: for every code(ex. 001-2023) its first corresponding values is located 6 column to the left and 10 rows down?

Comment: no. Actually this worksheet has different sections representing the months(ex. 001-2023 is January) in column J. My client wants to enter data through a Userform and the problem is, his entries are pretty wayward, i.e. he can put data for 001-2023 or even 002-2023 at anytime. The solution I had, was to determine through his entry in the Userform(combobox) the month and then determine where this section in the sheet is.

Comment: For example, if he selects the option 002-2023 then I have to loop through the column J and see where is the cell with 002-2023 and the next 003-2023 and that would be my Range to add the data. But I am out of ideas as to how determine this Range dynamically because every section would be growing as the data comes in and is not fixed